# Action Change Background Button. My Action doean't work with Button ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, button

I'm learning basic java. Now i learn JAVA Swing.
I have a problem with ActionListener , I don't know how to change color a button when process with ActionListener.
This is my code:

```
package mypack;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class myGame extends JFrame{
    public myGame() {
        createGUI();
    }

    public static void createGUI(){
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Game 25 Lights Out!");
        jf.setSize(557, 620);
        jf.setLocation(400,100);
        jf.setLayout(null);
        jf.setResizable(false);
        JButton[] jbt = new JButton[25];
        int left = 10;
        int top = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
        {
            jbt[i] = new JButton(" " + (i+1));
            jbt[i].setSize(110,110);
            jbt[i].setLocation(top*110, left);
            jbt[i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            jbt[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                }

            });
            top++;
            if(i==4||i==9||i==14||i==19){
                left += 115;
                top = 0;
            }
            jf.add(jbt[i]);
        }
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        myGame.createGUI();
    }

}
```

I need some guide at method actionPerformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
    JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
    // do something with the button
}
```

You can get the button that was clicked from the `ActionEvent`. Then you can just change the background.

Also, using this approach there is no need to create a new `ActionListener` for each button. You can create the `ActionListener` before the loop and add the same `ActionListener` to each button.

Comment: That way to implements ActionListener, I have learned. Thanks bro. I will create a new class Action to implement ActionListener. And I leanr about new knowledge: JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource(); :D